# Add a new column to .csv and populate with filename

Tags: python, csv

I'm relatively new to python and am trying to add a new column to all .csv files in a directory and populate them with the filename of the parent csv.

My code to date (from other parts of forum) allows me add a new column to a single file (listings1.csv) and call it 'FileName' and then populate this with other variables from within the file (row 0,1,2 etc).

I'd like to make two changes to this:

1. Add the actual name of the file (listings1) to FileName rather than data from another column
2. Run this for all csv file in the directory (listings1, listings2, listings3...) and just update the source file rather than create new ones (output1 etc)

Any advice appreciated

```
import csv

with open('listings1.csv','r') as csvinput:
with open('output1.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append('FileName')
    all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[1])
        all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I totally understood your question, but in worst case scenario this should give you some idea how to solve your problem.

```
import csv
import os

for file_name in os.listdir():
    with open(file_name,'r') as csvinput:
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('FileName')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(file_name)
            all.append(row)

        with open(file_name, 'w') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: Michal, Thanks for your help. I've tried to use this but am getting an error saying that listdir<> takes one argument and 0  given. Do I need to add in the absolute path here? Such as os.listdir('G:/Projects/Files') ?

Comment: Wasn't aware you're running python2. My solution is suitable for python3.

As you mentioned, in python2 you need to specify the path.

Comment: Thanks. This has worked for me. What would I need to do to undertake this task for .xls files rather than .csv?